# Push Notification via Azure Notification Hub doesn't show an icon on android

Tags: android, azure, notifications, xamarin.android

I use Azure Notification Hub with Xamarin Android and FCM. On the Notification Hub I use a custom Template, currently only with a message:

```
"{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$(message)\" }}"
```

It works so far that I receive the push notification in my Broadcast Receiver when the app is in the foreground. 
But there is no icon or entry shown in the notification bar. When I send a test message through the firebase console it appears as wished in the notification center.
I assume that I have to adjust the template. But with what? Is there a overview what options you have?

Comment: As far as I understand (and I haven't finished implementing this on android yet), there are 2 separate ways to handle notifications - inapp and out of app.  You've got the in-app bit working but you need some more code to update the icon and allow the os to put the number badge on for you.  Someone's blogged about it all here https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/so-i-just-implemented-push-notifications-in-awesome-xamarin-forms/

Comment: I had a look at the blog post. He uses GCM. That's the older presuccesor of FCM. What I'm puzzled about is that if I send a notification from Firebase it has the icon and the entry with the same code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, that there is a difference between a notification and a data message. The data message is not intended to be visible to the user.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

This is a GCM documentation. But I guess that the Notification Hub hasn't migrated to FCM.